How can I copy a picture from a flash drive to the iOS photo app?
I have a flash drive connected to my iphone via cable.  How can I copy a photo from the flash drive to my iPhone's photo app? I was only able to copy a photo from the flash drive to my iPhone's download folder via the default iOS file app.

I have an Apple SD card to Lightning adapter. It shows up as an importable resource in Photos on my iPhone. Is your flash drive connection very much different? I think you're going to need to provide a bit more detail on what sort of flash drive & cable.

If Photos doesn't directly support your Flash drive as an importable source then there's an indirect route once the photo is in Files.
A photo (or a selection of multiples) can be saved from the Files app into Photos by opening the image and sharing to Photos.

Open image
Press share
Scroll down and select Save Image

Importable sources in Photos may require some certain hardware combination perhaps. As I stated in the comments, I use an Apple SD card to Lightning Adapter that automatically adds a 5th button in the bottom row, that opens up an import dialog once an SD card is inserted.
